# Realm.io per-object permissions, compared to Firebase

Tags: permissions, firebase-realtime-database, realm, firebase-security

I'm considering switching from Firebase DB to Realm.io.

For my app, I need sharing items between users (in a many-to-many fashion).

In Firebase there is a permissions language (and the Bolt compiler).

What is the equivalent model in Realm.io?

Can I share objects between users, with controlled permissions?

EDIT: I'm talking about fine-grained per-object sharing, not coarse-grained per-database sharing.

Answer (score 1):

In the current release, permissions are defined per Realm (collection of objects), not fine-grained per object. You can obviously easily implement a "filtering" functionality unless you have strict security requirements that prohibit having some "irrelevant" data physically on a device despite it being fully encrypted.

If there are specific details you don't find sufficiently covered in the official [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#access-control) please elaborate what those are.