# Sharing individual objects between users in Realm.io

Tags: permissions, firebase-realtime-database, realm, firebase-security

I'm considering switching from Firebase to Realm.io.

Related to this: [Realm.io per-object permissions, compared to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576289/realm-io-per-object-permissions-compared-to-firebase)

I would like to be able to have fine-grained sharing of individual objects (not just the whole DB), between users. Including the option of sharing read-only to some users.

In firebase, there are the super-flexible per-node permissions.

Can I implement something like that in Realm?

Or are permissions just per-database?

If someone, who replies/comments, is affiliated to Realm, please note so :-).

Any thoughts are welcome and will be upvoted as long as they make sense and are on-topic :). Thanks.

Comment: I work at Realm and responded to the other SO question you refer to. Not sure how this question is different?
If you could elaborate on your use case it might be possible to come up with workarounds. But for now the hard core permissions are not per object, but per DB). Still interesting in understanding if per object permissions really are a hard requirement?